# Any Idea How To Send Selenium WebDriver Logs To Kibana

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, kibana

I never work on Kibana. Can any one help me as per requirement.
    I need to send Selenium logs to Kibana tool.
    Currently i am storing all logs in notepad file using printstream.

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(createLogReport(className));
//-Print on console and write to a file
TeeOutputStream myOut=new TeeOutputStream(System.out, fos);
System.lineSeparator();
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(myOut, true); //true - auto-flush after println
System.setOut(ps);
```

h 
With this code i am sending all System.out.println  logs in notepad file .
    But i have no idea related Kibana tool and how to send these logs in Kibana tools.
    Can anyone suggest me.

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I posted this question because i need help in coding if anyone know how to write code in selenium for kibana tools .  and if anyone share some code related this issue. This will helpful for me and for others. I have shared my code  currently i am using this code for storing logs in notepad file . but now as per requirement i need to send all logs to kibana .

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you are using [ELK stack](https://www.elastic.co/elk-stack). All you need to do is to learn how to feed the file produced into LogStash.

Kibana is the visualization engine, meanwhile LogStash is the data collection and parsing engine. You need LogStash to parse you WebDriver log file.